# Quickbook Intergration Using PHP

Tags: php, saml, quickbooks-online, simplesamlphp

I want to integrate Quickbook using php.

I downloaded php coding from https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat/

Also i downloaded http://simplesamlphp.org/download and OAuth files.

I have linked `Private key and certificate`. And also i have sepecified the `OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY` and `OAUTH_SHARED_SECRET`

I want to specify the `SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_ID`

I dont know where i get this PROVIDER ID.

Code : `define('SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_ID',  'PLEASE FILL IN');`

Can anyone tell, where i get this ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomerAccountData(AggCat) API and QB REST APIs are two different service.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs

**AggCat -** Private Key, Certificate , SAML all these are related to AggCat. If you want an AggCat integration, then refer the following link.

- Devkit & Sample apps -
  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits
- Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata

For Aggcat integraion, you should test all keys before integrating those with your application. It will help you to bring the application in running state quickly.
To test these keys, you can use apiexploler tool as mentioned in the following docs.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

**QB -** if you interested in integration with QB, then please refer

- Devkit & Sample apps - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits
  Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi
- Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

Thanks

Comment: i successfully got the response for my test account. In aggcat they have mentioned the url "financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com", How do i get the details of the account and customer details. Where should i change it.

Comment: Since you're using PHP, you might want to check out our open-source PHP QuickBooks framework. http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/ There's a quick-start example app for IPP/Intuit Anywhere here: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start