# Quickbooks integration using Aggcat

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I connected quickbook through the [PHPAggCat](https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat).

I created the token and key for `Customer Account Data`.

I created the test account and i used the test customer key and authentication token.

It works but while i am running it, i am getting the sample company name. And it showing around 2000 companies. I dont know where i am getting this.

I also tried with real account details but i am getting same result.

Also i dont know how to fetch the details of customer, invoice, payment, purchaseorder, account using PHPAggCat code.

And i used the path url `financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com` . This comes from `PHPAggCat`.

Answer (score 2):

AggCat and QuickBooks are two completely different APIs/services.

- **AggCat** is for accessing financial data (bank statements, checking
  accounts, etc.) from financial institutions (e.g. Bank of America,
  Wells Fargo, etc.). It has NOTHING to do with QuickBooks itself at
  all.
- The **QuickBooks API** (Intuit Anywhere, Intuit Partner Platform) are for
  accessing data from QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks for Windows.

It sounds like you're working with the wrong API.

This is where you should be starting if you want to work with QuickBooks:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

Although Intuit doesn't officially support PHP, we have a working open-source QuickBooks PHP library over here:

- [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/)

With a quick-start guide specifically geared towards Intuit Partner Platform / QuickBooks over here:

- [Intuit Partner Platform Quick-Start for PHP](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start)

Nightly builds of the code available here:

- [QuickBooks PHP DevKit - nightly builds](http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/)

And support forums available here:

- [QuickBooks PHP DevKit - support forums](http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewforum.php?id=2)

(and, of course, we also watch and answer questions on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in -[Quickbook Intergration Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802391/quickbook-intergration-using-php)

AggCat and QB are two different sets of API service.

customer, invoice, payment, purchaseorder, account - All these entities are available in Quickbook APIs. **AggCat** is nowhere related with these.

https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat - This is for AggCat Service. Not for Quickbook online.

For integration with Quickbook Online, please refer the following docs

- Devkit & Sample apps -
  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits
- Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

Thanks

Comment: I checked this but i didnt get any sample code for PHP. If possible can you send me the link for php sample code.

Comment: Then how can i integrate quickbook in my website. Is there any other way for integrating quickbook using php. If possible, Please suggest me some link

Comment: You need to use some open source PHP OAuth lib to consume the REST Endpoint service. I don't have any handy code snippet for PHP. If possible you can refer Java/.net code which is available in the link mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to connect the quickbook api using php soap?

Comment: No.. Quickbooks APIs are REST based.

Comment: You can refer the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838132/how-to-create-a-quickbooks-online-request-signature-in-php/18842032#18842032 .
Intuit will provide a php devkit soon(But I don't know the exact release date).Thanks