# How to create a Quickbooks Online request signature in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, signature, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I know QBO doesn't natively support PHP, but If I can get authenticated requests working, I can just use their API directly.

I've got the following pieces of data

```
appid
oAuth consumer key
oAuth secret key
```

I'm making an API call to this endpoint

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/<<my company id>>/item
```

I'm using googles oauth-php library to try to make this work. Here is the result

```
message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401
```

I'm obviously missing details on what to do here, ex: how to send the app id along with this. Does anyone have any experience or examples of getting a signature using PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of oauth are they using?

Comment: They are using oauth 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a complete [QuickBooks PHP library](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/) that has a working OAuth implementation.

You can download it here:

- [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/)

There's an authentication example at:

- docs/example_ipp_oauth.php

And data access examples at:

- docs/example_ipp_ids_5.php
- docs/example_ipp_ids_6.php
- docs/example_ipp_ids_7.php

The Google OAuth libs should work also- it's a standard OAuth implementation and we've used the Google OAuth libs successfully in the past.

Comment: Is there a way to make API calls directly without using your helper classes?

Comment: I made some modificaitions to your code, so now I can call this $ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();
$list = $ItemService->findByName($Context, $realm, "my-item");
echo json_encode($list); and get a JSON output of the raw output from the api skipping over the get() methods.

Comment: How do you handle adding deep data? Like for adding a bill, I need to add Line items. Thanks

Comment: $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line(); $Line->set...(); $Bill->addLine($Line);   The class names exactly mirror the XML nodes, so whatever the XML nodes are you just use the same for class names of child objects.

Comment: Do you support creating PurchaseOrders? I see it in your code, but the URI you generate is v2, and in their API explorer they only list purchaseOrders in v3.  Thanks!

Comment: Right now v3 is in private release, and only available to a select few companies. Thus, Intuit won't let me release PHP v3 libs publicly yet... but if you're interested, send me an e-mail and I'll start a conversation with Intuit and you and me and we'll see if we can hook you up.

Comment: @SeanClark Got it, will be in touch soon.

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 suggests some authentication issues.
So, please verify your tokens using ApiExplorer tool(or any other RestClient) and verify the request header.

Using V2 ApiExplorer, you can get the API endpoint.

- V2 - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

Apiexplorer donsn't show the OAuth tokens. So, I would suggest you to use the following link  to generate OAuth tokens. You can call the endpoint which you got from the Apiexplorer using the newly generated OAuth tokens. If it works, then use those tokens in you PHP application.

[**PN** - OAuth tokens don't depend upon API version ]

- https://appcenter.intuit.com/playground/oauth  [ It works with V2 ]

Thanks

Comment: In Step 3. Authorize Request Token, this doesn't make sense.  My app can't take the user away every time. I've already connected my app via the developer page.

Answer (score 0):

Since, this question is for v3 API access, you need to access- developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Refer to the ouath 1.0 docs to generate the signature as mentioned below:
http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/
http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process

Twitter example for generating signature-
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

**Sample RAW REQUEST AND RESPONSE headers-**

Request:

Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="CCCDOPwLGymIrFSHVZ317Qx",oauth_nonce="cddde-464b-458a-a718-2dcd8062616a",oauth_consumer_key="qyprtysdsdgJZUvWDFnPoiBh1ejZn",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1379398521",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="mwVUkoHnh%2BPLqZolso2rzX5aABM%3D"

Response Header:

Cache-Control : max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Connection : close
Content-Length : 1402
Content-Type : application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date : Tue, 17 Sep 2013 06:27:48 GMT
Expires : 0
intuit_tid : 0f9b5431-b713-4d55-ac24-c00f4e91848e
Server : Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Vary : Accept-Encoding
Via : 1.1 ipp-gateway-.net

Comment: Twitters generation won't help for intuit I believe. Intuit has some extra stuff involved.

I have those samples because the API explorer works - but I can't find a way to generate those through my own code - at least correctly.